# Tomcat and Apache webserver on same machine

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I need to install [ODK Aggregate](https://opendatakit.org/) on my CentOS 6 Server which is already running Apache HTTP on both 80 and 443 (80 is redirecting to 443 to force secure connection).

I was reading ODK and it require Tomcat 6. I read here and on StackOverflow that this two don't run at the same time without tweaking some config.

I've never installed Tomcat. The server is running a production site so I can't take it offline to test (and I don't have other server to play with).

For the time being I don't mind running tomcat on 8080, 8888, 5000, etc.

--

I'm using ODK Collect on Android to fill a form and send it to an aggregate server. They recommend Google App Engine or amazon but I need to access the data from the PHP site. (Since ODK save the data to a mysql database I think I won't have any problems reading it back).

Comment: I don't see a question here. You can most certainly run tomcat on 8080 without it interfering with apache on 80 and 443 if that is what you are asking.

Comment: @EddieDunn Hi! I'm asking if I would have no expected downtime on the server (i.e. apache stops working) because is a live server. I can do this overnight but if tomcat breaks my httpd setup I'm dead. :)

Comment: You don't need to worry about mod_proxy or apache to start. There are startup scripts included with the download. Just extract the app or place the war file into webapps and run the startup script and watch for errors and such in the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running Apache and Tomcat on the same computer is no problem. It's pretty common to run Tomcat on port 8080, run Apache on port 80/443, and use mod_proxy to allow Apache to serve apps hosted by Tomcat.

You might set up Apache so that any requests going to /app on port 80 get proxied to localhost:8080/app, which is Tomcat, but the end user doesn't know or care about any of this.

Comment: Hi! This is done by editing .htaccess o a VirtualHost on apache conf? The tomcat interface won't be accesible to the end user (they upload a form within the ODK Collect application. And the "data" is accesible by the main app (the one on the 80 port). mod_proxy is not needed in this case, isn't it?

Comment: Apache's docs say that ProxyPass is valid in the server config (apache2.conf/httpd.conf) or virtual host config, but not .htaccess.

I'm not sure I understand the scenario you're describing. If you need users to be able to access Tomcat, and you want them to do so using port 80 (which is Apache), then you need mod_proxy. If you don't want to serve Tomcat via port 80, then you don't need mod_proxy.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Users won't access tomcat (ODK installs a GUI but I will use the odk installation to interact with the android app. Then I have to read the information that was sent on the PHP application on port 443. ODK interface doesn't cover my needs.